# Internet Explorer Cookies With Path In Current Path Aren't Available In document.cookie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

For one of my projects I had the following paths available in a web application:

- `/one`
- `/one/two`
- `/one/two/three`

Each of the different paths are variable and used cookies as part of their variability, I had created the following cookies:

- `one=1; Max-Age=9600; Domain=.test.test.com; Path=/one; Expires=Wed, 30 Jul 2014 20:26:09 GMT`
- `two=2; Max-Age=9600; Domain=.test.test.com; Path=/one/two; Expires=Wed, 30 Jul 2014 20:26:09 GMT`
- `three=3; Max-Age=9600; Domain=.test.test.com; Path=/one/two/three; Expires=Wed, 30 Jul 2014 20:26:09 GMT`

When accessing the URL (I was running my test on http://test.test.com setup in my hosts file) at the following locations I received the following results:

- Visit `http://test.test.com/one` the correct cookie (`one=1`) was sent to the server, but `document.cookie` was empty.
- Visit `http://test.test.com/one/` the correct cookie (`one=1`) was sent to the server and `document.cookie` also had the correct cookie (`one=1`).
- Visit `http://test.test.com/one/two` the correct cookies (`one=1` and `two=2`) were sent to the server, but `document.cookie` only contained the first cookie (`one=1`).
- Visit `http://test.test.com/one/two/` the correct cookies (`one=1` and `two=2`) were sent to the server and `document.cookie` also had the correct cookies (`one=1` and `two=2`).
- Visit `http://test.test.com/one/two/three` the correct cookies (`one=1`, `two=2`, and `three=3`) were sent to the server, but `document.cookie` only contained the first two cookies (`one=1`, `two=2`).
- Visit `http://test.test.com/one/two/three/` the correct cookies (`one=1`, `two=2`, and `three=3`) were sent to the server and `document.cookie` also had the correct cookies (`one=1`, `two=2`, and `three=3`).

This utterly confounded me, and through a bunch of testing I was only able to find Internet Explorer being impacted by this issue, please see the answer for additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the constraints of my project I needed to have the ability to keep cookie names the same at each of these paths and also vary them by path, so I wasn't able to come up with any solution for my situation where I could use cookies without requiring a trailing slash at the end (which due to my constraints I cannot do).

If you are running into a similar issue there's a couple things that I can think of doing:

1. If the name of your cookies can vary, you could use different names for each of the paths and keep the path either at the root (`path=/`)
2. If the name of your cookies cannot vary but it doesn't matter if they go up a level in the path you could do that (in my case the cookie `three=3` could be placed up one directory at `path=/one/two` if my constraints didn't prohibit me from doing that.
3. If your constraints don't prohibit you from requiring trailing slashes you could simply have your webserver enforce trailing slashes and redirect to a path with them when they aren't present.
4. If you run into the same issue with similar constraints to mine you could just move to another storage device instead of cookies. There's other modern pieces such as localStorage and sessionStorage which would allow you to store your data in a more structured way so that you can handle the logic. Note: This only works when you don't need the data from the cookie server side.

In the end what I ended up doing was moving the cookie that I didn't need server side (`three=3`) to use a convention instead of configuration via cookie within the project and kept the other ones as is since the other two cookies (`one=1` and `two=2`) are only used when visiting the path `http://test.test.com/one/two/three` and so they are still available through `document.cookie` in Internet Explorer.